# Google Play Staged Rollout with modified screenshots

Tags: android, google-play, rollout

Using the Google Play Staged Rollout options, I can release a new version of my Android app to a small percentage of users. Depending on how successful it is, I would increase the percentage over a given period. I assume (because I can't find it documented) that if I roll the app out to 10%, then there is a spread of that percentage to both new and existing users of the app. (edit, see comment below)

If this is true, then people visiting the Google Play store would see the apps' screenshots and possibly use those visual images to decide on whether or not to install the app. If my new version has significantly different look, then the new users would not be seeing a true representation of the new app before choosing to download.

I suspect I already know the answer is no, but does anyone know for sure if new screenshots could be uploaded that will just appear to those who will receive the new version? I guess it really depends on how the staged rollout code/logic works, whether it is dependent on the Google Play app on the device, or not until the user actually clicks Download. Anyone have any experience they can share?

Comment: I can verify that in my example 10% of new users would get the app, and 10% of existing users, as noted here: [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329#ts=3280770,6035825)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So it seems from experimentation, that at this point, the Developers Console does not have a way to allow you to give updated screenshots (or promo text) to only those on a Staged Release. I posted a query to Google, which may or may not be answered, asking when such a feature of the Console could be made available. I'll post an answer if I get one.

**EDIT**

[topspeed's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347149/google-play-staged-rollout-with-modified-screenshots#comment64642505_25507567) includes an [official answer from Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en&ref_topic=3450989)

> **Tips for live staged rollouts**
>
> If your app update requires changes to the store listing, we recommend updating your store listing after your release rolls outs to 100% of users.

Comment: I have had a reply from Google who confirm this option is not currently available, but with their advice I have submitted a request for the feature to be added. So cross fingers....

Comment: So basically, these staged rollouts are only useful for some bugfix updates or other under-the-hood stuff, which does not need new screenshots...

Comment: That's not what the intention is - Google have used staged roll-outs when they release a new version of Play Services for example. It's just that until 100% of users are reached, you can't update the product configuration. More here: [link] (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en&ref_topic=3450989)

Comment: Exactly. They recommend not updating the store listing until a 100% is reached. So this means, it not advised to use it when the UI changes, since the screenshots and product descriptions wouldn't match the actual app. It's good to know.