# In play store staged rollout, the percentage applies to only existing users or both new and existing users?

Tags: android

Lets say I upload a new version of my app. I set the rollout to be global and rollout percentage to 5%. I know that 5% of the existing users will get the app update.

My question is, will 5% of the new users (going to the play store to download the app for the first time) get the new version or 100% of them will get it?

I tried to find the answer in the docs but I couldn't find it. On IRC, I was told 5% of the new users will get it.

Please post some official reference if you find one :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the official reference

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en

It would appear new users are randomized just like old users. So we cannot update description and say "Hey everybody, checkout this awesomeness and all those fancy screenshots" because some will get the old app, some will get the new app.

```
New and existing users are eligible to receive updates from staged rollouts and are chosen at random for each new release rollout.
```

So staged rollout are not that awesome marketing wise for a large app-update with new GUI.

According to our tests (June 2020) it also indicates some get the new version and some get the old version, when installing from playstore after uninstalling old app.

Also see this very similar question: [Google Play Staged Rollout with modified screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347149/google-play-staged-rollout-with-modified-screenshots)

Answer (score -2):

You can release an app update to production using a staged rollout. With a staged rollout, your update reaches only a percentage of your users, which you can increase over time.

Staged rollouts can only be used for app updates to production, not when publishing an app for the first time or creating an alpha or beta release.

**User eligibility & targeting**

1.New and existing users are eligible to receive updates from staged rollouts and are chosen at random for each new release rollout.

2.When you halt and then resume the rollout of your release, you'll be affecting the same set of users.

3.When you do a staged rollout of a new release before completing the rollout of the previous release, the new release will use the same group of users as the previous release (depending on the percentage of the rollout).

4.Your app update will be available to the percentage of users in your staged rollout, but it may take time for the full group to receive the update.

5.Users won't be notified if they receive a version of your app in a staged rollout.

6.If you choose specific countries for your staged rollout, the upgrade will be limited to users with Google Play accounts in those locations.